# Installation issue with nflscrapR package

Tags: r, magrittr

Having issues downloading nflscrapR. Not sure if anyone else has this issue. Output from trying to install below:

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/cciar/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'nflscrapR' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error: (converted from warning) package 'magrittr' was built under R version 3.6.3
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'nflscrapR'
* removing 'C:/Users/cciar/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/nflscrapR'
Error: Failed to install 'nflscrapR' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/cciar/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp6diEQG/file5f042b671761/nflscrapR_1.8.3.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Try restarting your R session and installing the `magrittr` package first, and then installing `nflscrapr` from github.

Comment: I have installed `magrittr` and I still get the error message.